# How to get elements from a nested dictionary that has the same value using python and bottle framework?

Tags: python, api, postman, crud, bottle

I am working with bottle framework in python, and I have created a dynamic @get route that gets all tweets with the same **user_id** based on the ID from the URL

Below is my nested tweets dictionary and the @get route

```
tweets= {
    "1" : {"user_id":"1", "name": "a", "email": "a@"}, 
    "2": {"user_id":"1", "name": "b", "email": "b@"},
    "3": {"user_id":"1", "name": "b", "email": "b@"},
    "4": {"user_id":"2", "name": "c", "email": "c@"},
}


@get('/user-tweets/<user_id>')
def _(user_id):
    
   for key in tweets:
      if user_id in tweets[key]['user_id']:
           
          response.content_type = 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
          return json.dumps(dict(tweets=tweets[key]))
```

So the problem is when I call this route using **postman** like this:

[image]

I get only the first element with the id that was passed through the URL, even though I should get all the items that have **"user_id": "1"**.

[image]

I tried the same exact thing on **jupyter** and surprisingly I got the results that I was expecting:

[image]

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here! Thank you in advance. As mentioned before, I am using python with bottle framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you return it stops finding the next items in your list.
You should store it in a list first.
try this

```py
@get('/user-tweets/<user_id>')
def _(user_id):
    user_tweets = []
    for key in tweets:
        if user_id in tweets[key]['user_id']
            user_tweets.append(tweets[key])
    response.content_type = 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
    return json.dumps(dict(tweets=user_tweets))
```

or if you can simplify by using list comprehension:

```py
@get('/user-tweets/<user_id>')
def _(user_id):
    user_tweets = [tweets[key] for key in tweets if user_id in tweets[key]['user_id']]
    response.content_type = 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
    return json.dumps(dict(tweets=user_tweets))
```